# Jquery Javascript Property Undefined

Tags: javascript

```
function dadosFormularios() {
    var dadosFormulario = {};
    var iterador = countForms;
    var i = 0;
    while (i < iterador) {
        dadosFormulario[i] = {};
        dadosFormulario[i]['a'] = $('#field\\[' + i + '\\]\\[a\\]').val();
        dadosFormulario[i]['b'] = $('#field\\[' + i + '\\]\\[b\\]').val();
        //alert(dadosFormulario[i]['a']);
        //alert(dadosFormulario[i]['b']);   
        i++;
    }
    var qstring = '';
    var tmp_qstring = [];
    var temp1, temp2;
    var aux_i = i + 1;
    alert(aux_i);
    for (var j = 0; j < aux_i; j++) {
        temp1 = dadosFormulario[j]['a'];
        alert(temp1);
        temp2 = dadosFormulario[j]['b'];
        //alert(temp1);
        tmp_qstring[j] = 'a' + j + '=' + temp1 + '&' + 'b' + j + '=' + temp2;
    }
    qstring = tmp_qstring.join('&');
    alert(qstring);
    window.location = 'dup1.php?' + qstring;
}
```

When i click on a button i call the above function and now I'm trying to send the data of the array of objects to another page as you can see in the code.

My problem is that i'm getting trouble when i set `dadosFormulario[j]['a'];` or `dadosFormulario[j]['b'];` to a var or set them directly in the `tmp_qstring` i.e. `tmp_qstring[j]=dadosFormulario[j]['b'];`. In chrome console i get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined

Comment: Where's `countForms` is defined?

Comment: In Chrome's console, you'll see a pause button. It tells the browser to break on JS exceptions. Press it two times to go into the "break on uncaught exceptions" mode. Then, the browser will halt when your exception occurs. At that point, you can follow the code:line link on the exception message and then hover over the local variables to see their values. If this doesn't help, try scaffolding your code with some `console.log` statements to print out the values of the variables. You'll soon see what going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix your loop to use:

```
j < i
```

Because both your array and your iterator variable `j` are zero-based. You have to stop iteration when your iterator reaches array length - 1 (`i` is the length in your case). This is typically the case for `for` loops over the length of an array.

If you iterate until `j <= i` your iteration index will go out of the end bound of the array.

Comment: You should explain why it should be less than and not equal to?

Comment: @epascarello True... I've added an attempt at explaining it.

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation but or my browser still not did the update or it's not working :/

i will update code in the post above

Comment: Or you could say that `i` is one greater than `dadosFormulario` length because the while loop. :)  +1 :)

Comment: Done. I was making two number diference loool. i.e. 0<2 and not 0<1.
It's working. Thank's a lot everyone.